# How can I get Mac notifications on my iPhone?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, notifications

There are plenty of solutions for iPhone notifications → Mac, but what about the reverse?

The only thing I found was "[Hermes](https://funk-isoft.com/hermes.html)" – which sounds awesome, but does not work for me at all. And no response from support in over a month.

Is there anything else?

Comment: MS has a Teams.app for iOS, why doesn't that work for you?

Comment: There are some other Mac-only apps I would also like to get notifications for.